# How can I use protocols in this case to change a variable in a uiview that I added programmatically?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I am sure I'm missing something quite silly, I have been able to always do similar stuff like this , but doesn't seem to be this time.

I have two classes, the first class is UIView and has a variable default to false. The second class is a UIViewController, so I tried simply setting the variable in second class and that doesn't work.

I am trying to use a protocol which can simply return me what I want, I would appreciate it if you can tell me why the value comes as nil. Basically what's wrong with the implementation of my protocol?

First Class:

```
    protocol  CustomizationDelegate{
    func activateCustomization() -> Bool?
 }

 class FirstClass: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{


    var modeDelegate: CustomizationDelegate?



    var myParam = false


//where I try to print my boolean to the console and I get nil 

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 400))
    //logging to console 
 let test = self.modeDelegate?.activateCustomization()
    print("testing", test )
    self.initialSetup()
}


fun initial setup(){
... initialization 
}

}
```

then in second class I do;

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

//implementing the protocol 
class SecondClass: UIViewController, CustomizationDelegate  {


// the first class  
lazy var customclass: FirstClass = {
    let dv = FirstClass()

    //I tried setting it true here 
    dv.myParam = true   

    return dv
}()


func activateCustomization() -> Bool? {
        return true
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//setting the delegate to self 
 calendarDayView.modeDelegate = self

 firstClass.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: srvceSetupWindow.frame.width, height: srvceSetupWindow.frame.height-80)

//adding fist class as a subview; seems fine except that myParam is still the default ; false 
 self.addSubview(calendarDayView)


enter code here
...other codes 
}
}
```

I have seen suggestions in SO, first if it was a parent-child relationship I could use a simple parent! check to get the same instance but it seems I can't because first class is UIView and not a controller.

Also, I have seen suggestions to implement protocol as I am trying to do which it seems I'm missing something. Appreciate any comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lot of variables here without a place they're instantiated. Please post all the relevant code and not just snippets :) You use `calendarDayView`, `firstClass`, but only have the declaration of `customClass`, so there's no way to know what's going on with them.

One problem I see is trying to get this: `print("testing", test )` to work.

It looks like you're creating the view here:

```
lazy var customclass: FirstClass = {
    let dv = FirstClass()

    //I tried setting it true here 
    dv.myParam = true   

    return dv
}
```

But you're never setting the delegate, and considering you're trying to print the result of activateCustomization in a constructor, it's impossible the delegate will have a value unless it's previously set in the initializer.

Is it possible you meant to add this to the class's frame in a didSet?